# Picture in picture with YouTube app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, youtube, picture-in-picture

I was surprised the iPhone YouTube app didn't provide [Picture in Picture](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207582) support by default:

[image]

But [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx5-ZKGQOiA&t=78s) has a *lot* of views and seems to show a simple way (basically go into settings and enable the feature).

However, when following the video's instructions, the option is not available in settings so it cannot be enabled.

The comments on the video indicate similar experiences.

#### Note

There is a short exchange in the comments which suggests YouTube Premium may be required, but then suggests that's not the issue (since people who have YT Premium also cannot access the feature):

> I’m ... trying everything and can’t get it

> You need youtube premium.

> I have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature used to be in beta on iPhone (as all Google beta features, no one know who will have it).

YouTube recently said in a statement that the feature is launching in the US only for Youtube Premium subscribers first. It will come later for all users. [Source](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/18/youtube-pip-support-rolling-out/)

Many Shortcuts provides the PiP mode, you can try one of these : [YouTube PiP](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/7ce1a2fea92845c0b32b212e40de702d), [PiP JS script](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/picture-in-picture-fix-youtube/)

Comment: Wow this answers everything. Just one thing, what is the YouTube PiP shortcut? Is it safe to use? (haven't used it before)

Comment: I'm using it right now.

It's made by the community so I recommend you to check the shortcut code on your side to make sure it's safe.